# Auto filter 2 columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have command buttons to auto filter, the first and second work, the third doesn't, I want to filter by two criteria and two columns. Any ideas?

```
    Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K4 : K1900").AutoFilter _
    Field:=1, _
    Criteria1:="No", _
    VisibleDropDown:=False
    End Sub
    Private Sub CommandButton7_Click()
    Cells.AutoFilter
    End Sub
    Private Sub CommandButton8_Click()
    Worksheets ("Sheet1")
        .Range("K4:K1900").AutoFilter
        .Range("C4:C1900").AutoFilter
        Field:=1,
        Criteria1:="No", _
        Criteria1:="City",_
        VisibleDropDown:=False
    End Sub
```

Comment: When you use `Autofilter` on column K, it puts the autofilter on it. When you do it again on column C, you're just removing the filter from from your range again.

Comment: That makes sense! how do I filter K with C after the filter on K has been applied? I want to see all fields containing "no" and "city"

Comment: K can be "yes" or "no" C can be "town" or " city"

Comment: I believe sktneer has provided the correct solution below

Answer (score 1):

You may try it like this...

```
Private Sub CommandButton8_Click()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C4:K1900")
        .AutoFilter field:=9, Criteria1:="No"       'field:=9 means the 9th column in the filtered range
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="City"     'field:=1 means the 1st column in the filtered range
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: error 1004 autofilter method of range failed, on field:=9

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the data. Did you try the exact code or modified it?

Comment: I copied it and changed field:=9 to field:=11 (because column 11 is column K) and changed field:=1 to field:=3 (because column 3 is column C)

Comment: In that case, did you change the first line to `With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A4:K1900")`?